# Remove duplicate from list

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to remove duplicate from list but I get `false`, this is my code :

```
remov([],[]):-!.
remov([T|Q],[T|R]):-not(member(T,R)),remov(Q,[T|R]).
remov([T|Q],R):-member(T,R),!,remov(Q,R).

member(E,[]):-!,fail.
member(T,[T|Q]):-!.
member(E,[T|Q]):-member(E,Q).
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27989470/772868) is a pure and fast version

Answer (score 1):

The above implementation of predicates `remov/2` and `member/2` excessively "use" the meta-logical constructs `(!)/0` and `not/1`, which ruins almost all declarative aspects—forcing us to focus on a vast number of painstaking details. For details, see [prolog-cut](/questions/tagged/prolog-cut) and [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity).

Let's re-implement `remov/2` based on [`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/4609915) and `sort/2`, like so:

```
remov(Xs,Ys) :- 
   iwhen(ground(Xs), sort(Xs,Ys)).
```

How does this work?

- The builtin predicate `sort/2` sorts lists of Prolog terms according to the [standard order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26720685/4609915), eliminating duplicate items in the process.
  Note that `sort/2` may not preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) if the input list contains variables.
- `iwhen/2` ensures sufficient instantiation when using `sort/2`.

Sample queries:

```
?- remov([1,2,3,1,2],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,3].

?- remov(Xs,Ys).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```